# Application unable to sign in with Office 365 API when deployed to test

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, preview, office365

I have integrated office 365 API preview in one of my applications and it works well in localhost but when deployed to staging server I get the following error message on windows login page:

```
Additional technical information:
Correlation ID: 1f01000e-acab-4e6c-ba4f-b48039ed6d08
Timestamp: 2014-07-20 12:00:29Z
AADSTS70000: The redirect address 'http://test.unicom.dk/4ef0faf9-a531-4011-8c51-0be2b39d52c2.axd' is not valid.
```

Any help is much appreciated.
I have updated the azure configuration and it still works on local but on test I think I have moved a step forward. As in the screenshot I get back the code and everything but nothing gets displayed;
[image]

Comment: Well I got it working after I setup my deployed website using https

Comment: Turns out I was missing https in the deployed website. Office365 API communication on a deployed site only happens if the site is working on https

Comment: Could you write you comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing https in the deployed website.
Office365 API communication on a deployed site only happens if the site is working on https